# SoapUI load testing - JDBC check after last request

Tags: soapui

Is is possible to add a JDBC check to a load test in SoapUI that is only perform once after the load test has finished? I want to validate that the number of saved items is bigger than a predefined value.

Comment: Sure, just do it in the TearDown Script. Hints are here https://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL and here http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/tips---tricks.html#10-Use-a-JDBC-Driver-from-inside-a-groovy-script .

Comment: @SiKing That was indeed something I've tried already but I couldn't get my test to fail. Even not if I did something like ´assert false´ in the groovy code.

Comment: I thought you said "load test"?

Comment: Yep, but I want to make sure that at least X requests have been send. And I don't want to manually check this actually..

Answer (score -1):

To connect to the database, you can use something like:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils

sql = Sql.newInstance( 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://serverName/dbName-CLASS;domain=domainName', 'username', 'password', 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' )
// register MySQL JDBC driver
GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" )
row = sql.firstRow('select columnA, columnB from tableName')    // or whatever it is you're looking for
```

To set the failure, you can use something like:

```
if(row.columnA > 100)    // or whatever your use-case is
    testRunner.fail('bad result')
```

All this comes from official documentation.

Comment: testRunner.fail('bad result') doesn't do anything in a TearDown script. I've already tried thoes things. I'm not getting any message anywhere that my test has failed or something.

Comment: @GregD Perhaps it would be helpful if you read through [ask] and improve your question accordingly.